Не удается загрузить образ на sd карточку

Необходима помощь, так как не первый раз слетает установка образа на sd карту. Причем слетает всегда на разном ходе прогресса.
Карточка новая, samsung. В чем тут может быть трудность?
Журнал программы RUFUS:
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Write error at sector 6750208: [0x000001B1] A device which does not exist was specified.
Retrying in 5 seconds...

Write error at sector 6750208: [0x00000037] The specified network resource or device is no longer available.
Retrying in 5 seconds...

Write error at sector 6750208: [0x00000037] The specified network resource or device is no longer available.
Retrying in 5 seconds...

Write error at sector 6750208: [0x00000037] The specified network resource or device is no longer available.
Opened \\.\PhysicalDrive3 for shared write access
Remounted \\?\Volume{d01013d6-acd2-11ef-8769-08d40cec633b}\ as E:
Re-mounted volume as E: after error


Флешку сменить бы

Не первая sd карта, со всеми одно и тоже. Начинает записывать и на половине, якобы не находит usb флешу... У меня sd корточки вставляются в флешку, думаете в ней делать? Один раз мне удалось записать, в том что она была нулевая, не пользованная... Сейчас не из дешевых sd карточку взяла, samsung. Один раз записала, правда с образом ошиблась. Отформатировала и все, началось

Быть может подскажете хорошую программу которая форматирует в fat32, уже многие попробовала, не выходит, то одно то другое.

Добавила логи в моменте когда слетает...

Флеку новую купи. Эта подделка

Флешку новую купите. Эта подделка!

Правы, все дело в самой флешке. Именно в флешке, в которую вставлялась sd карта. А карточки все хорошие.

а, тоже может быть)


Скачайте и установите программу для записи образа: Рекомендуется
использовать Raspberry Pi Imager или Etcher. Я использовал Imager.
Вы можете скачать их с официальных сайтов
https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/imager/imager_latest.exe.
Запустите программу записи: Откройте Raspberry Pi Imager или Etcher.
Выберите образ операционной системы: В программе выберите
загруженный файл образа .img. Выберите целевую microSD-карту:
Убедитесь, что выбрана правильная microSD-карта, так как все данные
на ней будут удалены.

Начните процесс записи: Нажмите кнопку для начала записи . Подождите, пока процесс завершится.


По вашим логам, больше похоже на проблему с железом. Я предлагаю попробовать на другом компьютере, с другим картридером и с другой sdcard, жестоко конечно, но проблема может быть в любом компоненте. Карту можно проверить, вставив ее в мобильное устройство, отформатировать и записать файлы, вытащить, пощупать, не должна быть очень горячей, вставить и прочитать файлы. Картридер может читать карты, но и убивать их, у меня такой есть. Проверить только заменой. Комп самый маловероятный , но не исключаю, желательно проверить на другом.  Если получится записать, можно искать виновника, по очереди исключая.

Увы, все тоже самое. Начинает записывать и на 5-10% слетает... Я уже в отчаяние...

@Лена дополнил ответ.

Все дело в флешке было, да, она грелась, спс
